# Remove each element that occrus more than 'N' times problem

Tags: java, loops, sorting, arraylist

I'm kind of stuck with a small bug in my code and I hope you could help me!

I have an ArrayList and I want to remove all the elements that repeat more than 'N' times. My solution works just fine in most cases, but when it comes to N=1 and ArrayList size is more than 30 or so it skips one element so it's not unique.  Its index is random( i mean I tried to find a special index where the problem is hidden, but I could not).

Here comes the code

```
while(isSorted!=true) {
for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    counter = 0;
    temp = test.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < test.size(); j++) {
        if (temp == test.get(j)) {
            counter++;
            if (counter >= maxOccurrences) {
                test.remove(j);
               }
            }
          }
        if(counter<maxOccurrences){
           isSorted=true;
       }
    }
 }
```

If I just repeat this block of code one more time it deletes this element and everything is fine. I'm trying to understand why it would skip one not unique element. I could use HashSet for this particular case(when N=1) but it feels like cheating a little bit.
I hope I was clear with my question and provided all information that is needed.
Thank you in advance. Peace and love!

Comment: Could you provide sample input of data you observe a strange behavior?

Comment: Here it comes! ArrayList is : {58, 14, 9, 1, 31, 36, 54, 41, 13, 14, 1, 20, 26, 35, 10, 25, 31, 63, 62, 32, 30, 40, 71, 31, 38, 44, 31, 29, 8, 34, 14, 43, 54, 76, 62, 58, 60, 33, 12, 54, 4, 38, 6, 40, 8, 68, 39, 41, 57, 58, 13, 46, 37, 70, 23, 75, 13, 17, 28, 44, 44, 67, 3, 19, 0, 15, 24, 55, 49, 51, 44, 2, 51, 19, 40, 1, 76};


And the result is : [58, 14, 9, 1, 31, 36, 54, 41, 13, 20, 26, 35, 10, 25, 63, 62, 32, 30, 40, 71, 38, , 29, 8, 34, 43, 76, 60, 33, 12, 4, 6, 68, 39, 57, 46, 37, 70, 23, 75, 17, 28, , 67, 3, 19, 0, 15, 24, 55, 49, 51, 2] As you can see 44 remains 2 times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that using HashSet would be better in terms of asymptotics, since it would not exceed O(n) by the sum rule.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<>();
        integers.forEach(integer -> {
            if(newMap.containsKey(integer) && integer != null)
                newMap.put(integer, newMap.get(integer) + 1);
            else
                newMap.put(integer, 1);
        });
    return newMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x->x.getValue().equals(numberOfDuplicates))
                .map(x->x.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And what about your code it is also better to use `equals()` instead of `==`, because if the numbers are greater than `127` and less than `-127`, your code will always work incorrectly.

The problem is that with `remove` , you need to reduce `j` by 1, because if the elements go in a row, the next element will move to the past `j`, and you won't delete it, because you're already on `j+1` element

```
if (counter >= maxOccurrences) {
     test.remove(j);
     j--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Messing with a List while you're iterating over it can be hazardous to your health. I suspect that your index-based loops are getting fooled by calls to `remove`, which cause shifts.

Your algorithm is something on the order of N^3. Consider sorting the array first if you're allowed to do so, or using additional storage to reduce search times by counting all the array elements in a single pass as suggested by another respondent.